# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset (AWS and Bouncy Castle)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, bouncycastle

Let's imagine that we have an ECS instance which has a running Java application that calls DynamoDB to update some item(s). Most of the time it works fine, but every now and then there is a `SocketException: Connection reset` thrown. It doesn't break the system, but it annoys quite much and I would like to understand what could be the reason for that. For now my research brought me only to Bouncy Castle, meaning that it could be throwing something internally that leads to the connection reset, but I am not sure.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream$Record.fillTo(RecordStream.java:442)
at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream$Record.readHeader(RecordStream.java:481)
at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(RecordStream.java:216)
at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(TlsProtocol.java:879)
at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.readApplicationData(TlsProtocol.java:842)
at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketWrap$AppDataInput.read(ProvSSLSocketWrap.java:797)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.fillInputBuffer(BHttpConnectionBase.java:330)
at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.isStale(BHttpConnectionBase.java:350)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.validate(CPool.java:71)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.validate(CPool.java:45)
at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(AbstractConnPool.java:256)
at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(AbstractConnPool.java:198)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:306)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:282)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy8.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1346)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6999)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6966)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeUpdateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6451)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6415)
```

What could cause this?

P.S. bcprov-jdk18on, bcpg-jdk18on, bcpkix-jdk18on are used as bouncy castle dependencies.